# Thunderbolt 2 (MacBook Pro 2013) / Ubuntu 18.04 Display Issue

Tags: 18.04, display, displayport, thunderbolt

Good day,

I have ubuntu 18.04 running on a 2013 model MacBook Pro.

This Mac model has two thunderbolt 2 ports on the left side.

One port is working flawlessly; however, the other (nearest to the screen) is not.

Ubuntu is recognizing the display (hdmi adapter) on that port, but nothing is displayed on the monitor.

The same monitor and adapter work fine in the other port.

Any ideas on how to solve this? I tried setting it to mirrored mode using xrandr (as seen in other posts on here), but that doesnt work either.

Here is xrandr output when the hdmi device is plugged in:

```
root@UbuntuBook:/etc/X11# xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 331mm x 207mm
   2880x1800     59.99 +
   2880x1620     59.96    59.97  
   2560x1600     59.99    59.97  
   2560x1440     59.99    59.99    59.96    59.95  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   2048x1152     59.99    59.98    59.90    59.91  
   1920x1200     59.88    59.95  
   1920x1080     60.01    59.97    59.96*   59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      70.07    60.00  
   800x600       72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Note: I am not dual booting, so I cannot see if it works on the MacOS side.

Comment: Have you tried thunderbolt ports?
This seems to be known issue to HDMI ports.
[https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/no-signal-with-hdmi-or-dp-0-ports-on-macbookpro10-1-gt-650m-only-dp-1-works/49777/5](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/no-signal-with-hdmi-or-dp-0-ports-on-macbookpro10-1-gt-650m-only-dp-1-works/49777/5)